# Linspace with anonymous function skipping every second value

Tags: arrays, matlab, anonymous-function

I have a really simple problem but can't get it done.

I want to produce a *linspaced* sequence between two values of an anonymous function. If I do it with values its no problem and looks like this

```
n = 5;
left = 1;
right = 3;

y = zeros(n, 1);
x = linspace(left, right, n)';

q = zeros(2*n, 1);
q(1:2:end) = x
q(2:2:end) = y
```

But the same thing is not possible with anonymous functions as boundaries. My attempt looks like this but I would really appreciate a better solution

```
n = 5;
left = @(t) 0.5 * t;
right = @(t) 2 * t^2 + 5;
diff = @(t) right(t) - left(t);

q = @(t) [];

for i = 1:n
    q = @(t) [q(t) i*diff(t)/n 0*t];
end

q(0.5)
```

I hope you can help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need anonymous function here? you can do the same as in your working code, but inside a function that gets `t` as an input and calculate `left` and `right`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Adiel I made the following answer

```
function [Q] = reference_configuration(left, right, n, t)

l = left(t);
r = right(t);
diff = r - l;

x = linspace(0, diff, n);
y = zeros(1, n);

q = zeros(1, 2*n);
q(1:2:end) = x;
q(2:2:end) = y;

end
```

Maybe it helps someone. Thank you!

Comment: Your output `Q` is never set, this should presumably be `q`. Also `q(2:2:end) = y` does nothing, you're assigning zeros to array elements that were already zero. And why do you need `left` and `right` be anonymous functions, if you evaluate them with another input parameter. Why can't the user of the function not directly pass the left and right boundaries as scalar values?